Vector Clock Diagrams for Distributed Systems using TikZ
I am trying to draw a vector clock diagram (primarily for showing causality in distributed systems). What I want is something like this (but not exactly, this is merely an example):

Here is what I have so far:

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\newcommand{\clockdiagram}[3]{
% #1: number of processes
% #2: list of events in the format (process_id, x_pos, label (can be scalar or vector))
% #3: list of messages in the format (from_event_index, to_event_index), where event_index refers to index in #2

\begin{tikzpicture}[
>=Stealth,
event/.style={circle, fill},
timeline/.style={->, thick},
connection/.style={->, dashed}
]

% Create timelines and events
\foreach \process [count=\i from 1] in {1,...,#1} {
\node (start) at (0, -2*\i) {P\i};
\node (end) at (10, -2*\i) {};
\draw[->, thick] (start) -- (end);
}
\foreach \event [count=\j from 0] in #2 {
\pgfmathsetmacro{\proc}{{\event}[0]}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xpos}{{\event}[1]}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\eventindex}{{\event}[2]}
\node[event,label=above:{\eventindex}] at (\xpos,-2*\proc) (e\j) {};
}
\foreach \conn in #3 {
\pgfmathsetmacro{\from}{{\conn}[0]}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\to}{{\conn}[1]}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\fromtime}{{#2}[\from][2]}
\draw[connection] (e\from) -- (e\to) node[midway,above] {\fromtime};
}

\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

% Example usage
\clockdiagram{2}{{
(1, 2, {1, 0}), % TODO: Display as [1, 0] instead of 10
(2, 5, 5) 
}}{{
(0,1)
}}

\end{document}

I want to ensure that [1, 0] is displayed in the form of a vector (any representation works, it just has to be semantically different from a scalar), and not as 10.
Edit: This is my first attempt to tikz properly, and so there might be some mistakes. The DSL has basically come out of experimentation, and I am happy to learn better ways to do the same thing. Essentially, what I want is a macro for which I can specify the events with time, along with messages between events.

your code fails to compile due to undefined macros. how is \pgfmathprintmatrix defined?

How complex will your drawing be? Will there be more than one? Why do you think you need THIS kind of macro? Thank you

@cfr corrected. Thanks for catching that! It   isn't supposed to be there.

@MS-SPO roughly as complex as the example. About 15 events, and 6-7 messages between them. Unless there is no way of doing it using a macro, I would rather not painstakingly draw everything out.

Thank you. So 1 drawing, 3 lines, 15 circles and labels, 7 lines with arrow tips? If so, that’s no big deal and less error prone than introducing your syntax …

Can you complete your question by showing what would be the ideal DSL, syntax, to define such kind of diagrams?

@MS-SPO not one drawing, I will probably need it >10 times, which is why I preferred a macro.

@projetmbc the complete DSL can be seen in the last few lines of the MWE.

Ok. // I suggest you review the comments made so far and update your question to improve clarity of what you need, and why (all those little details from the comments are easily overlooked by future readers). Thank you

Wrt https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/724173/vector-clock-diagrams-for-distributed-systems-using-tikz#comment1802001_724173, the "syntax" looks very lisp-ish to me ;-) which qualifies for some further remarks in your question.

@MS-SPO I am not sure what makes the question unclear. The lispy DSL is merely an artifact of experimentation, and I would appreciate any better way of doing the same thing. This is my first time tikz-ing, and any tips are helpful :)

If it was clear, there hadn't been comments requesting more details. My suggestion: just summarize them, EDIT and add to your question. // Have to stop our discussion now, as this is no chit-chat-forum ;-)

what is DSL? ..

@cfr DSL = Domain Specific Language. For example, forest uses a DSL.

@projetmbc Thank you. (something specific to Distributed Systems also seemed possible.)

Here is one way to do it.
The process is bottum-up (i.e. starting simple) combined with refactoring (generalize multiplicates). Any such code can be considered transitory, i.e. as a kind of snapshot, which works and still can be made more universal.
With two typos ...

Bottom-up idea

draw the three lines AND put nodes there via pos
move the nodes names a, b, ... inside the nodes to reduce visual noise
put the vector-labels
connect all relevant nodes
put some extras, like P1..P3
on the way introduce styles as needed (which is already one act of refactoring)

Universal macro as you intend
Following this approach I suggest using a mixed approach. First, let's have a look at a section where refactoring/generalization is simple to do:
% ~~~ refactored ~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\vlab[3]{\foreach \v [count=\j] in {#2}%
        \node[#3] at (#1\j) {\v};}
...
    % ~~~ vector labels ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    %% BEFORE refactoring
%   \foreach \v [count=\j] in {(1,0,0), (2,0,0), (3,1,0), 
%                              (4,1,0), (5,1,2), (6,1,2), (7,1,2)}
%       \node[vlu] at (A\j) {\v};
%       
%   \foreach \v [count=\j] in {(0,1,0), (2,2,0), (6,3,2)}
%       \node[vld] at (B\j) {\v};
%       
%   \foreach \v [count=\j] in {(1,0,1), (0,0,2)}
%       \node[vld] at (C\j) {\v};
        
    %% AFTER refactoring
    \vlab{A}{((1,0,0), (2,0,0), (3,1,0), (4,1,0), (5,1,2), (6,1,2), (7,1,2))}{vlu}
    \vlab{B}{(0,1,0), (2,2,0), (6,3,2)}{vld}
    \vlab{C}{(1,0,1), (0,0,2)}{vld}

I started with the 3 \foreach loops, which could be absorbed easily by macro \vlab. The order of parameters is historical: it may be better to chose a different order (which is a refactoring consideration).
Whether or not you want to even absorb the nodes "name" A, B, C also, is a matter of preference. In this place code would look more complicated afterwards with little to no benefit (which is a refactoring decision).
Second, a place where it's harder to do:
    % ~~~ lines with events ~~~~~~~~~
    \draw (0,4) --  node[ev,pos=.1] (A1) {a}
                    node[ev,pos=.3] (A2) {b}
                    node[ev,pos=.4] (A3) {c}
                    node[ev,pos=.6] (A4) {d}
                    node[ev,pos=.7] (A5) {f}
                    node[ev,pos=.8] (A6) {g}
                    node[ev,pos=.95] (A7) {h}
        +(10,0);
...

AFAIK, these nodes can't be absorbed by a \foreach loop from Tikz. But you can use other loop constructs, if you want. My preference would be: use it as-is, copy&paste & modify as needed. I.e. leave as-is (which is a refactoring decision).
If you follow this approach, with frequent compile, back-up and refactoring, you'll approach the macro you started out more and more, but in an organic way. And it certainly will look very diffent in the end on code level.
By intention I left some places without refactoring:

this happens anyway
is both transitory and a demo

Here, moving the nodes options into a style is what a refactorer can't overlook ;-)
    % ~~~ axis labels ~~~~~~~~~
    %     unrefactored
    \node[anchor=east] at (0,4) {P1};
    \node[anchor=east] at (0,2) {P2};
    \node[anchor=east] at (0,0) {P3};

The rest is pretty straight forward ...

\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

% ~~~ refactored ~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\vlab[3]{\foreach \v [count=\j] in {#2}%
        \node[#3] at (#1\j) {\v};}

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    ev/.style={circle,fill=white,draw,font=\small},
    >={Stealth},
    vlu/.style={cyan,yshift=6mm,font=\small},   % task; refactor vlu+vld
    vld/.style={cyan,yshift=-6mm,font=\small},
 ]
    % ~~~ lines with events ~~~~~~~~~
    \draw (0,4) --  node[ev,pos=.1] (A1) {a}
                    node[ev,pos=.3] (A2) {b}
                    node[ev,pos=.4] (A3) {c}
                    node[ev,pos=.6] (A4) {d}
                    node[ev,pos=.7] (A5) {f}
                    node[ev,pos=.8] (A6) {g}
                    node[ev,pos=.95] (A7) {h}
        +(10,0);

    \draw (0,2) --  node[ev,pos=.3] (B1) {i}
                    node[ev,pos=.4] (B2) {j}
                    node[ev,pos=.88] (B3) {k}
        +(10,0);
        
    \draw (0,0) --  node[ev,pos=.2] (C1) {l}
                    node[ev,pos=.5] (C2) {m}
        +(10,0);
    
    % ~~~ vector labels ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    %% BEFORE refactoring
%   \foreach \v [count=\j] in {(1,0,0), (2,0,0), (3,1,0), 
%                              (4,1,0), (5,1,2), (6,1,2), (7,1,2)}
%       \node[vlu] at (A\j) {\v};
%       
%   \foreach \v [count=\j] in {(0,1,0), (2,2,0), (6,3,2)}
%       \node[vld] at (B\j) {\v};
%       
%   \foreach \v [count=\j] in {(1,0,1), (0,0,2)}
%       \node[vld] at (C\j) {\v};
        
    %% AFTER refactoring
    \vlab{A}{((1,0,0), (2,0,0), (3,1,0), (4,1,0), (5,1,2), (6,1,2), (7,1,2))}{vlu}
    \vlab{B}{(0,1,0), (2,2,0), (6,3,2)}{vld}
    \vlab{C}{(1,0,1), (0,0,2)}{vld}
        
    % ~~~ connectors ~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[->] (A2) -- (B2);
    \draw[->] (B1) -- (A3);
    \draw[->] (C2) -- node[pos=.7,anchor=west] {note} (A5);
    \draw[->] (A6) -- (B3);
    
    % ~~~ axis labels ~~~~~~~~~
    %     unrefactored
    \node[anchor=east] at (0,4) {P1};
    \node[anchor=east] at (0,2) {P2};
    \node[anchor=east] at (0,0) {P3};
    
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

